# How to render a high resolution image from emoji string

Tags: swift, uiimage

I am trying to take an emoji and convert it to a 160x160 high resolution UIImage, but it seems like I am getting a grainy picture from my method.

```
 func toImage(withDimension dimension: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: dimension)

    let stringBounds = (self as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(stringBounds, false, 3.0)

    let xCenter = (stringBounds.width - CGFloat(dimension))/3.0
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xCenter, y: 0.0), size: stringBounds)
    UIColor.clear.set()
    UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: stringBounds))

    (self as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image!
 }
```

Called:

```
"".toImage(withDimension: 160.0)
```

[image]

There is a similar thread to this, but it seems the problem was left unsolved. Is it possible to produce a high resolution 160x160 image from emoji? I am using Aspect Fill content mode

Comment: With a dimension of 160 you are actually attempting to create an image that is 480x480.

Comment: When I use a dimension of 160.0/3.0, I get a 53x53 image, not 160.0 though

Comment: What is the value of `stringBounds`? The final image will be 3 times that size due to the scale of 3.

Comment: @rmaddy (174.0, 190.9375)

Comment: @Sulthan I actually need to have a transparent background for my case, am I creating the image wrong?

Comment: @Brejuro My bad actually. You are doing that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Refactored the solution:

```
/// Creates an optional `UIImage` from text
/// - Parameters:
///   - dimension: image dimension
///   - font: font
/// - Returns: Optional `UIImage`
func toImage(withDimension dimension: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> UIImage? {
    let stringBounds = (self as NSString).size(withAttributes: [.font: font])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(stringBounds, false, 3)
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    let centerX = (stringBounds.width - dimension) / 3
    let rect = CGRect(
        origin: .init(x: centerX, y: .zero),
        size: stringBounds
    )
    UIRectFill(rect)
    (self as NSString).draw(
        in: rect,
        withAttributes: [.font: font]
    )
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
 }
```